# List<Dictionary<string, string>> Manipulating data with linq

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, dictionary

I'm having difficulty extracting data in the last lines due to some misunderstanding of mine.  I was expecting 10 Keys, and I get all Keys...

I just want to package the data, and ask it questions with Linq...spelling out criteria: How many hours did "Chad" take as a technician for SSR 4321?

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>> SSRList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, string> SSR = new Dictionary<string, string>();

SSRList = Util.Cache(() =>
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"I:\Mfg\Test Development Workstations\PI\Lee K\DougBLNData.txt"))
    {
        if (line.Contains("*"))  //indicates new record/end of record
        {
            SSRList.Add(SSR);
            SSR = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        if (line.Length < 1) continue;  //ignore Whitespaces

        if (line.Contains(": "))
        {
            string[] lineSplit = line.Split(new string[] { ": " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (SSR.ContainsKey(lineSplit[0].Trim()))
            {
                lineSplit[0].Trim().Dump("Offending Key");
            }
            else
            {
                SSR.Add(lineSplit[0].Trim(), lineSplit[1].Trim());
            }
        }
    }
    SSRList.Add(SSR);
    return SSRList;
});


SSRList.First().Dump();

SSRList.Take(10).Where(x => x.Keys.ToString() == "ServiceTechHrs").Dump("All ServiceTechHrs values selected");
```

Here is an example of data to parse:

```
Status:  In Process
Prefix:  18-
PlantLoc:  Lewiston
Date:  08/10/2018
Department:  FT
Time:  08/10/2018 02:08:30 PM
StationID:  177
Fixture:  initialization 
Supervisor:  Da Mi
PMOnly:  
PartNo:  0735
SerialNum:  
FailedStep:  Validate/Validate firmware
Reason:  Script
OtherReason:  
Details:  Initalization failure 
Urgency:  Script Problem
Date_1:  08/10/2018
Time_1:  08/10/2018 04:24:06 PM
Date_2:  
Time_2:  
ProblemFound:  
SolutionCode:  
Solution:  8/14/2018  TSR  SSR 18-07121 was also entered.  8/14/2018 GAH. The 735 units with B1492-6 boards fail during Test Flash possibly due to a timing issue in the script.  These particular board types have 1GB of flash and take longer for the flash test.  I will need to contact TMESoftware to see if the WAIT time can be increased for the 735 units with B1492-6-XX boards.  8/14/2018 GAH.  Details:  https://jira.metro.ad.selinc.com/browse/MTEN-1814
ServiceTechHrs:  
ServiceEngHrs:  
DocHistory:  Assignee #1 xxxxx xxxxx assigned by Alex xxxxx on 08/10/2018,Request submitted by xxxxx on 08/10/2018,Request created by xxxxx Olander on 08/10/2018
Mailed:  1
CloseDate:  
HoldOn:  
HoldOff:  
Authors:  *
ISAuthors:  IS Notes Developers; LocalDomainAdmins; LocalDomainServers
MgrData:  
SaveOptions:  1
IniDate:  08/10/2018
IniTime:  08/10/2018 02:08:30 PM
MOT:  
RequestNum:  07011
Initiator:  xxxxx xxxxx
Notification:  LWS Flex Leaders
ServiceTech:  xxxxx xxxxx
ServiceEng:  
SolutionCode_1:  
FixtureCheck:  Stop
Solution_1:  8/14/2018  TSR  SSR 18-07121 was also entered.  8/14/2018 GAH. The 735 units with B1492-6 boards fail during Test Flash possibly due to a timing issue in the script.  These particular board types have 1GB of flash and take longer for the flash test.  I will need to contact TMESofre to see if the WAIT time can be increased for the 735 units with B1492-6-XX boards.  8/14/2018 GAH.  Details:  https://jira.metro.ad.com/browse/MTEN-1814
$Revisions:  08/10/2018 02:17:28 PM,08/10/2018 02:17:29 PM,08/10/2018 04:24:06 PM,08/10/2018 04:24:07 PM,08/13/2018 08:34:47 AM,08/14/2018 02:59:06 PM,08/14/2018 03:02:59 PM

SupDoc:  SSR 18-07121
```

Ideally I would like to keep the data packaged as SSRs (the example above), and keep them in a list I can .Where .Select, etc.

Comment: Maybe it's my misunderstanding.. but doesn't every line contain a "line.Contains("")"?

Comment: Why not dump and then take 10?

Comment: The funky character that sets, looks like an arrow or a heart, didn't show up when I pasted it in.  Presume it's an asterisk for these purposes.

Comment: @Monofuse I'm not following you...

Comment: Well you took then 10 and then assumed that each of the items you were dumping only contained 1 item

Comment: Honestly I don't think I got what you were doing :p :)

Comment: @Monofuse "Where(x => x.Keys.ToString() == "ServiceTechHrs")" I thought would have limited it to ten results, since there is 1 "ServiceTechHrs" in each dictionary.  Thank you for the help - I'm surely missing something here yet.

Comment: @Alex Filipovici Would you be able to help Alex, you seemed to come up with something clever and concise on another similar question.  I just want to package the data, and ask it questions with Linq...spelling out criteria: How many hours did "Chad" take as a technician for SSR 4321?